# Set default value on a field in a table only if null

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database table (SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition) that has a column with a nullable value and I want it to have a default value field only if the data I am entering is null; otherwise the field should get the passed value. I have read something about triggers in SQL Server that could accomplish that (pretty difficult for me) and I was wondering if there is some easy way for it.

Comment: This is how default values work.  If null then it populates with the default value. Otherwise it uses the value provided in the insert query.  Have you actually tried placing a default value on a field?

Comment: I did set the default value, but the value is still null when inserting null data. I have a table which has a nullable FK and its value is set to a fixed value but when I am inserting data with null value it remains null.

Comment: @TamasIonut: if you define a default on a column, you **must NOT** specify that column in your `INSERT` statement and **NOT** provide a `NULL` value for it... just leave that column out of your `INSERT` statement and then the defined default value will be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE some_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT DF_some_field
  DEFAULT 'some_default_value'
  FOR some_field
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175912%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on how to set default column values in sql server.

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDefaultColumns.aspx

When you select a column in the management studio gui, you can see "Default Value or Binding" in the column properties.